Sorting Lists of list
I have a list of list containing numbers. I want to sort one of the list and then I want to ensure that other lists are rearranged in the order of the sorted list.All lists are of same size.
import numpy as np

# Example list of lists with numbers
list_of_lists = [[5, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7], [6, 3, 2]]

# Convert lists to NumPy arrays
arrays = [np.array(lst) for lst in list_of_lists]

# Sort the first array
sorted_array = np.sort(arrays[0])

# Initialize a list to hold the reordered arrays
reordered_arrays = [sorted_array]  # Start with the sorted array

# Function to reorder an array based on the sorted positions of its elements
def reorder_array(arr, sorted_positions):
    reordered_arr = np.full_like(sorted_array, fill_value=np.nan)  # Initialize with NaNs
    for pos, val in enumerate(sorted_positions):
        if val in arr:
            idx = np.where(arr == val)[0][0]  # Find the index of the current value in the unsorted array
            reordered_arr[pos] = arr[idx]  # Place the value from the original array at the correct position
    return reordered_arr

# Reorder the other arrays
for arr in arrays[1:]:
    sorted_positions = np.argsort(arr)  # Find the sorted positions of elements in the current array
    reordered_arr = reorder_array(arr, sorted_positions)
    reordered_arrays.append(reordered_arr)


print(reordered_arrays)


Will you always be wanting to sort based on the values in the first sub-list with the list (arrays[0]) or could it be any of the sub-lists?

Any sublist will do Its just that once I have sorted one of them the others should get rearranged in the same order

Can you please give me your expected result? Based on your question, here is my simplified code:
import numpy as np

# Example list of lists with numbers
list_of_lists = [[5, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7], [6, 3, 2]]

# Convert lists to NumPy arrays
arrays = np.array(list_of_lists)

# Get the indices that would sort the first array
sorted_indices = np.argsort(arrays[2])

# Reorder all arrays based on these sorted indices
reordered_arrays = arrays[:, sorted_indices]

# Convert back to a list of lists if needed
reordered_lists = reordered_arrays.tolist()

print(reordered_lists) # [[9, 8, 5], [7, 4, 1], [2, 3, 6]]

You can change np.argsort(arrays[...]) according to your need.

I think the OP wants to sort the first inner list, so it should be sorted_indices = np.argsort(arrays[2])

If you have this array:
list_of_lists = [[9, 5, 8], [1, 4, 7], [6, 3, 2]]
arr = np.array(list_of_lists)
print(arr)

[[9 5 8]
 [1 4 7]
 [6 3 2]]

Then you can do:
arr2 = arr[:, np.argsort(arr[0])]
print(arr2)

Prints:
[[5 8 9]
 [4 7 1]
 [3 2 6]]


You can use the key function of Python's sorted function, e.g.,
list_of_lists = [[5, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7], [6, 3, 2]]

# Convert lists to NumPy arrays
arrays = np.array(list_of_lists)

# list index to sort on
sortidx = 2

sorted_array = np.array(sorted(arrays.T, key=lambda a: a[sortidx])).T

print(sorted_array)
[[9 8 5]
 [7 4 1]
 [2 3 6]]

